# Parser Error Message: The entry 'DefaultProfileProvider' has already been added

Tags: asp.net, parsing, web-config

I have tried everything to fix this issue and cannot seem to get this error removed.

here is my web.config code:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <!--
           For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
     -->
     <configuration>
     <configSections>
     <!-- For more information on Entity Framework                                                                                                                   configuration,visit                                                                                               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<section name="glimpse" type="Glimpse.Core.Configuration.Section, Glimpse.Core" />
<section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel,             Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
           </configSections>
         <connectionStrings>
          <add name="MobileReportsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MobileReports.csdl|res://*/Models.MobileReports.ssdl|res://*/Models.MobileReports.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=sqlgii02da1.dev.ardentmc.com\gii;initial catalog=MobileReports;User ID=MobileReports;Password=mobile;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
            <add name="MacEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Shared.Identity.Mac.csdl|res://*/Shared.Identity.Mac.ssdl|res://*/Shared.Identity.Mac.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=sqlirad01d.dev.ardentmc.com;initial catalog=Shared;persist security info=True;user id=IdentityClient;password=Id3ntityCli3nt;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
       <appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="logoLarge" value="~/Images/dhslogo.png" />
<add key="logoSmall" value="~/Images/dhslogo20x20.png" />
<add key="ApplicationUserGroup" value="Department of Homeland Security" />
<add key="ApplicationName" value="COP Mobile" />
<add key="ApplicationHeader" value="DHS COP Mobile" />
<add key="JQueryMobileCSS" value="~/Content/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.css" />
<add key="JQueryMobileThemeCSS" value="~/Content/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.0.css" />
<add key="ThemeCSS" value="~/Content/themes/dhs-jqm-theme-1.css" />
<add key="SiteCSS" value="~/Content/Site.css" />
<add key="JQueryJS" value="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" />
<add key="JQueryUIJS" value="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js" />
<add key="JQueryMobileJS" value="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js" />
<add key="UtilitiesJS" value="~/Scripts/Utilities.js" />
<add key="HeaderActivationJS" value="~/Scripts/HeaderActivation.js" />
<add key="NavbarsJS" value="~/Scripts/Navbars.js" />
<add key="MobilePopupJS" value="~/Scripts/MobilePopup.js" />
<add key="LayersConfigFile" value="default_layers.xml"/>
<add key="ActiveIncidentsFeed" value="https://gii-dev.ardentmc.net/tokenauth/georss/COPLite/?token=446A6778-9F41-40ED-8A76-923E40B07CED" />
         <add key="FeedRefreshInterval" value="180000"/>
       <add key="FileDownloadPrefix" value="https://gii-dev.ardentmc.net/tokenauth/georss/CopLiteService/GetFile.ashx?token=446A6778-9F41-40ED-8A76-923E40B07CED&amp;fileId=" />
     <add key="GiiHome" value="https://gii-dev.ardentmc.net"/>
     <add key="UseAuthentication" value="false" />
     <add key="AuthenticationName" value="HSIN" />
      <add key="ProxyUrl" value="" />
     </appSettings>
     <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
           <assemblies>
          <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,        PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          </assemblies>
            </compilation>
             <httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="102400" requestValidationMode="4.5" /> <!--targetFramework="4.5" **I took this out**-->
          <machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1" validationKey="8A0FDB3F447F173B7D2821B17E41B3350733FE098D0B403F93C8E41269F57ADF88C6009A8F9071C3A7B1AF9382DAC219A3A5CE0BF0C8D2DA3E2ACBF155B87B5D" decryptionKey="15C8F55337FBC0FD7F83404F0BF6FA472614C94D1E6F3EB5" validation="SHA1" />  
           <authentication mode="Forms">
           <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" name=".GIIFORMSAUTH" protection="All" domain="ardentmc.com" />
           </authentication>
          <identity impersonate="true" />
         <pages>
             <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="MobileReportsEntities" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="MobileReportsEntities" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="MobileReportsEntities" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="2880">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="MobileReportsEntities" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
     <httpModules>
        <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" />
         </httpModules>
          <httpHandlers>
           <add path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" />
           </httpHandlers>
          </system.web>
          <system.webServer>
           <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
           <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
             <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
             <remove name="Glimpse" />
              <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
                  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
                 <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
                   <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
                  </handlers>
                <modules>
                 <remove name="Glimpse" />
                   <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
                   </modules>
                  </system.webServer>
                     <runtime>
                     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
                    <dependentAssembly>
                  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
               </dependentAssembly>
               <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
             <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
             <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
         </assemblyBinding>
        <legacyHMACWarning enabled="0" />
         </runtime>
       <entityFramework>
           <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
          </entityFramework>
             <system.net>
             <defaultProxy enabled="true" />
             <settings>
                    <!-- This setting causes .NET to check certificate revocation lists (CRL) 
             before trusting HTTPS certificates.  But this setting tends to not 
             be allowed in shared hosting environments. -->
                    <!--<servicePointManager checkCertificateRevocationList="true"/>-->
                  </settings>
             </system.net>
                 <uri>
                 <!-- The uri section is necessary to turn on .NET 3.5 support for IDN (international domain names),
         which is necessary for OpenID urls with unicode characters in the domain/host name.
         It is also required to put the Uri class into RFC 3986 escaping mode, which OpenID and OAuth require. -->
                <idn enabled="All" />
                     <iriParsing enabled="true" />
                       </uri>
               <glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
<!-- If you are having issues with Glimpse, please include this. It will help us figure out whats going on. 
  <logging level="Trace"/>-->
<!-- Want to use Glimpse on a remote server? Ignore the LocalPolicy by removing this comment.
  <runtimePolicies>
    <ignoredTypes>
      <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
    </ignoredTypes>
         </runtimePolicies>-->
          </glimpse>
            <system.identityModel>
             <identityConfiguration>
              <claimsAuthenticationManager type="ArdentMC.Security.Identity.ClaimsManager, ArdentMC.Security.Identity"/>
                   <claimsAuthorizationManager type="ArdentMC.Security.Identity.AccessManager, ArdentMC.Security.Identity" />
                  <claimsAuthenticationManager type="ArdentMC.Security.Identity.ClaimsManager, ArdentMC.Security.Identity" />
             </identityConfiguration>
           </system.identityModel>
          </configuration>
```

does anyone have any idea how to fix this error message i keep getting? 
any advice or help would be greatly appreciated. 
thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using a website or a web application (when deployed within IIS) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issues. i was using visual studio to ghold multiple projects and my web config file was overlapping with another project i had in visual studio...i just needed to disconnect the project i wasnt using and that fixed the duplication errors.